# The number of divisors of 2700 including 1 and 2700 equals

Tags: divisor-counting-function

I don't really know how to approach this kind of problems, is there any trick or formula for this?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Definition

Comment: Try first with small examples, like $2,3,4,5,6,9,12,15,18$ and see if you can find a pattern. It's tightly linked to prime factorisations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Factor the number in question:
$$2700=2^2 \times 3^3 \times 5^2.$$

Any divisor must be a combination of these prime factors, with the exponent of $2$ at most $2$, the exponent of $3$ at most $3$, etc. The number of factors is then $3\times 4\times 3 = 36$ because the first exponent can range from $0$ to $2$ (3 possibilities), the second exponent can range from $0$ to $3$ (4 possibilities), and the third can range from $0$ to $2$ again (3 possibilities).

In general, if we have
$$N = \prod_{i\ge 1}{p_i^{e_i}}$$
then the number of factors including $N$ and $1$ is $\prod_{i\ge 1}{e_i+1}$.